# How to insert values in database with loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

```
$value1=$_POST['csvval'];
 foreach( $valueas $key=>$value )
{
$qry=mysql_query("insert into tablename(value) values('$value1)");
echo $value; 
}
```

This is not working for inserting rows
How to insert each row values in database with for loop.?

Comment: Because your syntax is invalid...!? Try a `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: you are already putting your insert query inside foreach loop. This will run based on the parameter you have passed inside it.

Comment: I think there is syntax error in query missing  single quote. try this ... $qry=mysql_query("insert into tablename(`column_nmae`) values('$value1')");

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
$qry = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename(value) VALUES($value1)");
```

Comment: do u getting value in output ?

Comment: I want to insert each and every row in database mutliple times

Answer (score -2):

Add curly braces around $value (because it's inside single quotes). Else, it will evaluate to `'$value'`.
Also, $value is an associative array. You get the value by: `$value[$key]`

```
insert into tablename (value) values ('{$value[$key]}')
```

Comment: If its an integer, that is okay. Else, if it's a string (with spaces in between), you have to quote it.

Comment: The baces aren't needed as the qry is wrapped around double quotes, meaning every `$var` will be interpolated in PHP so your comment about single quotes and the needed of the braces is not true